# Can't get spell check to work on LibreOffice ver. 7.3.5.2

Tags: libreoffice, spell-checking

We are running ver. 20.04 LTS with LibreOffice ver. 7.3.5.2 and we can not get spellcheck to work in Writer. It capitalizes the first word after a period ok but that's it. We had no problems with Writer ver. 6.4.7.2 and it's still in use on another machine. We have used the same settings as that ver. 6.4.7.2 to no avail as well as just about every other combination of settings and it still won't work.

[image]

Comment: Open LibreOffice Writer. Clck on **Tools > Options** from the menu. Scroll down to **Language Settings > Writing Aids** on the left panel. Take a screenshot of the **Options - Language Settings - Writing Aids** Window. Upload the screenshot [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422596/edit).

Comment: There is the screen shot.

Comment: The screenshot looks OK to me. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I have the same setup v7.3.5.2 on 20.04 LTS and there does appear to be an issue with LO Writer spellchecking which I have been unable to resolve yet. Maybe report your issue to https://ask.libreoffice.org/tags/c/english/5/writer to see if one of their experts have an answer for it. Share a link to your post in comments here and I'll keep an eye out for it...

Comment: I have the same setup LibreOffice v7.3.5.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. Ican't reproduce the problem. [See my screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/e4vVSRZ.png).

Comment: It seems like it can't find the dictionary. See the second screen shot. I've checked the LibreOffice paths and they point to a wordbook. I have no idea how the internal paths work?

Comment: There is a fault somewhere... and I can reproduce it both in 20.04 and 22.04 with v7.3.5.2 - if in the bottom panel you have English (USA) set, the spellchecker works fine,but if you right click on the language setting to change the language setting to English (UK) and retype your text, the spellchecker will not function and misspelt text is not underlined. This is a [link to Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/spellcheck-english-uk-in-lo-7-3-5-2-fails-to-function-correctly/80458?u=grahamlees) where I have posed a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

From Ask LibreOffice which resolves the issue on my Ubuntu system.

The package required for LO is `hunspell-en-gb` and the safest way to install it (which I did) is with synaptic package manager which will include all the correct dependencies.

[image]

After installation the spellchecker works as intended.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't fix it. I did both hunspell-en-gb and -us and neither fixed it. So, I did the whole writer package and that didn't fix it either. I hate to do it, but uninstalling and reinstalling LibreOffice may be my only option? But if the problem exists after that??

Comment: Another item that I just remembered, LibreOffice doesn't recognize any USB memory stick also.

Comment: The last step? I uninstalled LibreOffice, then deleted everything that had the name libreoffice (directory's, files, etc.) left on the system, and then installed a fresh copy of libreoffice and used synaptic package manager to insure that hunspell-en-gb & us were installed. Guess what, the sucker still doesn't spell check and still doesn't recognize a USB memory stick! Would appreciate an alternative to libreoffice or better yet a fix to their bug(s).

Comment: did you try to reopen the same documents? If so, the attributes for those documents will already be saved with it. Try opening a new document from scratch and trying the spell checker. You'll need to ask a separate question about alternatives.

Comment: I GIVE UP! I've tried everything discussed in this thread to no avail. This morning I gave it a final shot by uninstalling LibreOffice both from the Ubuntu Software function and again from terminal (apt-get remove --purge, clean and autoremove). Then installed it again via the Ubuntu Software function. The spell check and finding a USB memory stick problems still exist!

Comment: So my thinking is either that is a bug in the software or the copy in the Ubuntu Software Library is corrupted? I've wasted way to much time on this so will be relegated to use our old backup (slow) machine running LibreOffice ver. 6.4.7.2. That combination actually is much faster than the current version running on a more powerful machine. Go figure